# Jquery Newly inserted table rows disappear after 2 seconds

Tags: jquery

the newly inserted rows just showed for 2 secs.then disappeared...

```
$item = $( "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"inputBig\" /></td>"+ 
               "<td><input type=\"checkbox\" checked=\"checked\" /></td></tr>");

$item.prependTo($("#tbodyPI")).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code alone will not cause the row to disappear.

You have some other code which is removing it.

Comment: I removed almost everything except a simple table on the page. but i still get the same behavior. any guess of what kind of code may remove it? thanks a lot!

Comment: thanks. i found the problem. the button I click to add new row post back and refreshes the page. changed it to input type button and solve the problem.

Comment: @Jnew: You can accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.